# xmlhttp request in a node-red function node

Tags: http, get, xmlhttprequest, ibm-cloud, node-red

Is it possible to make http GET requests from within a node-red "function" node.
If yes could somebody point me to some example code please.

The problem I want to solve is the following:
I want to parse a msg.payload with custom commands. For each command I want to make an http request and replace the command with the response of a HTTP GET request.

```
expl:
msg.payload = "Good day %name%. It's %Time% in the %TimeOfDay%. Time for your coffee";
```

The %name%,%TimeOfDay% and %Time% should be replaced by the content of a Get request to http://nodeserver/name,..., http://nodeserver/Time.

Answer (score 1):

thnx Hardilb,

After half a day searching I found out that the http-node can also be configured by placing a node just before it setting the

```
msg.url = "http://127.0.0.1:1880/" + msg.command ;
msg.method = "GET";
```

I used the following code to get a list of commands

```
var parts = msg.payload.split('%'),
len = parts.length,
odd = function(num){return num % 2;};

msg.txt= msg.payload;
msg.commands = [];
msg.nrOfCommands = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++){
    if(odd(i)){
        msg.commands.push(parts[i]);
        msg.nrOfCommands = msg.nrOfCommands + 1;
    }
}
return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid doing asynchronous or blocking stuff in function nodes.

Don't try to do it all in one function node, chain multiple function nodes with multiple http Request nodes to build the string up a part at a time.

You can do this by stashing the string in another variable off the msg object instead of payload.

One thing to looks out for is that you should make sure you clear out msg.headers before each call to the next http Request node